# Updating a view with new ObservableCollection causes duplicates in layout

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a simple app that displays content from an ObservableCollection of Labels depending on which button in an ObservableCollection of buttons is clicked. With the press of a 'Refresh' button, I want to replace the labels and buttons, and display those instead. For this, I have bindings to respective ObservableCollections, and I do .Clear() on each of the collections before refreshing. The ObservableCollections update correctly, but the elements that are rendered on the screen are both the old items along with the new ones. My layout does not seem to update itself, rather add a new layout beside it with the updated items. The following screenshots illustrate the problem:

On Load:

[image]

On Refresh:

[image]

How do I stop the old items (first button 1 and 2, Initial item 1) from displaying?

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp">

    <StackLayout>
        <Button Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" Text="Load" />
        <Button Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" Text="Refresh" />
        <local:BindableStackLayout
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Items="{Binding ButtonCollection}"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            VerticalOptions="Start" />
        <local:BindableStackLayout
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Items="{Binding ItemCollection}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

MyViewModel.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public ObservableCollection<View> ButtonCollection { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<View> ItemCollection { get; set; }
        public Command LoadCommand { get; set; }
        public Command RefreshCommand { get; set; }
        public List<string> ItemList { get; set; }
        public int SelectedItem { get; set; }
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            ButtonCollection = new ObservableCollection<View>();
            ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<View>();
            LoadCommand = new Command(Load);
            RefreshCommand = new Command(Refresh);
        }

        public void SelectItem(int item)
        {
            SelectedItem = item;
            for (int i = 0; i < ItemList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (item == i)
                {
                    ItemCollection[i].IsVisible = true;
                    ButtonCollection[i].BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
                else
                {
                    ItemCollection[i].IsVisible = false;
                    ButtonCollection[i].BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Load()
        {
            ItemList = new List<string> { "Initial item 1", "Initial item 2" };
            for (int i = 0; i < ItemList.Count; i++)
            {
                int copy = i;
                ButtonCollection.Add(new Button { Command = new Command(() => { SelectItem(copy); }), FontSize = 32, Text = (i + 1).ToString(), HeightRequest = 100, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand });
                ItemCollection.Add(new Label { Text = ItemList[i] });
            }
            SelectItem(0);
        }

        public void Refresh()
        {
            ItemList = new List<string> { "Updated item 1", "Updated item 2", "Updated item 3" };
            ItemCollection.Clear();
            ButtonCollection.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < ItemList.Count; i++)
            {
                int copy = i;
                ButtonCollection.Add(new Button { Command = new Command(() => { SelectItem(copy); }), FontSize = 32, Text = (i + 1).ToString(), HeightRequest = 100, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand });
                ItemCollection.Add(new Label { Text = ItemList[i] });
            }


      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ItemCollection.Count);
        SelectItem(0);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

BindableStackLayout.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace TestApp
{
    class BindableStackLayout : StackLayout
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Items), typeof(ObservableCollection<View>), typeof(BindableStackLayout), null,
                propertyChanged: (b, o, n) =>
                {
                    (n as ObservableCollection<View>).CollectionChanged += (coll, arg) =>
                    {
                        switch (arg.Action)
                        {
                            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                                foreach (var v in arg.NewItems)
                                    (b as BindableStackLayout).Children.Add((View)v);
                                break;
                            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                                foreach (var v in arg.NewItems)
                                    (b as BindableStackLayout).Children.Remove((View)v);
                                break;
                        }
                    };
                });

        public ObservableCollection<View> Items
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<View>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a seperate Action for when the list is cleared. So this should probably work:

```
switch (arg.Action)
{
    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
        foreach (var v in arg.NewItems)
            (b as BindableStackLayout).Children.Add((View)v);
        break;
    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
        foreach (var v in arg.NewItems)
            (b as BindableStackLayout).Children.Remove((View)v);
        break;
    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
        (b as BindableStackLayout).Children.Clear();
        break;
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction?view=netcore-2.0

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Clear()` on an `ObservableCollection<T>` doesn't raise several `CollectionChanged` events with an `Action` of `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove`.

Try to handle `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset` in your `BindableStackLayout` class or remove the items one by one in your view model:

```
public void Refresh()
{
    for (int i = ItemCollection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        ItemCollection.RemoveAt(i);
    for (int i = ButtonCollection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        ButtonCollection.RemoveAt(i);

    ItemList = new List<string> { "Updated item 1", "Updated item 2", "Updated item 3" };
    for (int i = 0; i < ItemList.Count; i++)
    {
        int copy = i;
        ButtonCollection.Add(new Button { Command = new Command(() => { SelectItem(copy); }), FontSize = 32, Text = (i + 1).ToString(), HeightRequest = 100, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand });
        ItemCollection.Add(new Label { Text = ItemList[i] });
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ItemCollection.Count);
    SelectItem(0);
}
```

Comment: There might be something wrong with my Remove in BindableStackLayout, but trying to remove each item this way gives me a NullReferenceException. Handling the Reset in BindableStackLayout works.

Answer (score 0):

After clear, just re-initialize the collections like below,

```
 ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<View>();
 ButtonCollection = new ObservableCollection<View>();
```

Comment: Re-initializing the collections will break my bindings